# Traductions: are lips movements changed for every language?

Tags: dialogue, film-techniques, animation

If I watch *The Simpsons* in French for example then the lips movements match with the oral traduction.

**Question:** In general, are lips movements in animated films/shows modified to match traductions in languages different from the original one?

This seems like a lot of work to me, but I don't see how there could be a perfect match if it wasn't done.

Comment: I'd doubt it's even done for *The Simpsons* (or *any* other work), since as you say it would be *hell* of a work to reanimate basically the whole thing. Rather than that it probably just *looks* like it matches to you because the French dubbing department does a really good job, coupled with subjective factors from your side, like being used to dubbing or subconciously *wanting* it to match.

Comment: There exists software designed to match words in the new language to lip-sync from the original animation (or live action film), which facilitates translation.

Comment: While admittedly only asking for feature films, this might be an exact duplicate of [Do feature-length animation studios reanimate characters' mouths for foreign language dubs?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/16887/49) (It even has an answer pertaining to France.)

Comment: @Napoleon Wilson Yes, my question is pretty much an exact duplicate. Sorry :[

Comment: Don't worry. That happens and isn't necessarily a bad thing. I had to look for that older question, too, I only had the advantage of remembering that we had something like this before.